# How would I find an unknown pattern in an array of bytes?

Tags: ruby, database, reverse-engineering

I am building a tool to help me reverse engineer database files. I am targeting my tool towards fixed record length flat files.

What I know:
  1) Each record has an index(ID).
  2) Each record is separated by a delimiter.
  3) Each record is fixed width.
  4) Each column in each record is separated by at least one x00 byte.
  5) The file header is at the beginning (I say this because the header does not contain the delimiter..)

Delimiters I have found in other files are: ( xFAxFA, xFExFE, xFDxFD ) But this is kind of irrelevant considering that I may use the tool on a different database in the future. So I will need something that will be able to pick out a 'pattern' despite how many bytes it is made of. Probably no more than 6 bytes? It would probably eat up too much data if it was more. But, my experience doing this is limited.

So I guess my question is, how would I find UNKNOWN delimiters in a large file? I feel that given, 'what I know' I should be able to program something, I just dont know where to begin...

```
 # Really loose pseudo code
 def begin_some_how
   # THIS IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH...
   # find all non-zero non-ascii sets of 2 or more bytes that repeat more than twice.
 end

 def check_possible_record_lengths
   possible_delimiter = begin_some_how
   # test if any of the above are always the same number of bytes apart from each other(except one instance, the header...)
   possible_records = file.split(possible_delimiter)
   rec_length_count = possible_records.map{ |record| record.length}.uniq.count
   if rec_length_count == 2 # The header will most likely not be the same size.
     puts "Success! We found the fixed record delimiter: #{possible_delimiter}
   else
     puts "Wrong delimiter found"
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
possible = [",", "."]

result = [0, ""]
possible.each do |delimiter|
    sizes = file.split( delimiter ).map{ |record| record.size }
    next if sizes.size < 2

    average = 0.0 + sizes.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }  
    average /= sizes.size    #This should be the record length if this is the right delimiter

    deviation = 0.0 + sizes.inject{|sum,x| sum + (x-average)**2 }

    matching_value = average / (deviation**2)
    if matching_value > result[0] then
        result[0] = matching_value
        result[1] = delimiter
    end

end
```

Take advantage of the fact that the records have constant size. Take every possible delimiter and check how much each record deviates from the usual record length. If the header is small enough compared rest of the file this should work.

Comment: This looks great, however I was more asking how do I find an unknown pattern? I do not want to define possible delimiters because they could be any set of random bytes.

Comment: @Peter Black That's why you have to test all possibilities. Think about it this way: if it was you looking at the file instead of your computer, how would you guess what are separators and what aren't? Try some and see which ones behaves like a separator.

Comment: So the only way to 'find' unknown patterns is by looking? I was kind of hoping there would be some sort of algorithm that could test for patterns. Like:
1) find all non-zero non-ascii sets of 2 or more bytes that repeat more than twice.
2) test if any of the above are always the same number of bytes apart from each other(except one instance, the header...).